# Error when export enum from src/types on React Native Project

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native

I have added to my types folder an enum but when I try to use it, it throws the following error:

`Error: Unable to resolve module types from /Users/mindera/Documents/Projects/Vocovo/elp-vocovo-mobile-app/src/screens/register/Register.tsx: types/types could not be found within the project or in these directories:
node_modules
31 |
32 | /* Types */

> 33 | import {RegisterProps, ButtonEnum} from 'types';

```
at ModuleResolver.resolveDependency (/Users/mindera/Documents/Projects/Vocovo/elp-vocovo-mobile-app/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-plugin-metro/node_modules/metro/src/node-haste/DependencyGraph/ModuleResolution.js:139:15)
at DependencyGraph.resolveDependency (/Users/mindera/Documents/Projects/Vocovo/elp-vocovo-mobile-app/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-plugin-metro/node_modules/metro/src/node-haste/DependencyGraph.js:277:43)
at Object.resolve (/Users/mindera/Documents/Projects/Vocovo/elp-vocovo-mobile-app/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-plugin-metro/node_modules/metro/src/lib/transformHelpers.js:169:21)
at Graph._resolveDependencies (/Users/mindera/Documents/Projects/Vocovo/elp-vocovo-mobile-app/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-plugin-metro/node_modules/metro/src/DeltaBundler/Graph.js:473:35)
at Graph._processModule (/Users/mindera/Documents/Projects/Vocovo/elp-vocovo-mobile-app/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-plugin-metro/node_modules/metro/src/DeltaBundler/Graph.js:261:38)
at async Graph._traverseDependenciesForSingleFile (/Users/mindera/Documents/Projects/Vocovo/elp-vocovo-mobile-app/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-plugin-metro/node_modules/metro/src/DeltaBundler/Graph.js:249:5)
at async Graph.traverseDependencies (/Users/mindera/Documents/Projects/Vocovo/elp-vocovo-mobile-app/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-plugin-metro/node_modules/metro/src/DeltaBundler/Graph.js:157:9)`
```

My guess is that exporting enum from absolute path is causing an error on Typescript or Babel. When I use relative path as '../../types' the error does not occur. Also I have enums in component folders that does not throw any error.

```
//generics/generic.ts

export enum ButtonEnum  {
  Primary = 'primary'
} 

//types/index.ts
export * from 'generics/generic.ts'
```